# Inserting formatted text using accessibility API in Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, accessibility, nsattributedstring

I'm trying to insert some formatted text in Cocoa using accessibility API. This is what I've done:

```
NSFont *font = [NSFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:14.0];
NSDictionary *attrsDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:font forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
NSAttributedString *attrString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"hello, world" attributes:attrsDictionary];
AXError error = AXUIElementSetAttributeValue(element, kAXValueDescriptionAttribute, attrString);
// element is an instance of 'AXUIElementRef' with role 'AXTextArea'
```

The error I always get is `kAXErrorIllegalArgument (-25201)`. If I try to insert non-formatted text then it works fine.

So, does anyone know how to insert a formatted text using accessibility API?

Comment: what`s your kAXValueDescriptionAttribute?

Comment: @JonasSchafft kAXValueDescriptionAttribute is a constant.

Comment: @kamaldeepsinghbhatia Yes, I'm trying to insert formatted "hello, world"

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can set the description, value or title to an attributed string. Maybe you can get the attributed string with `AXUIElementCopyParameterizedAttributeValue` but there is no `AXUIElementSetParameterizedAttributeValue`.